# How to get 10 millisecond older mouse position with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, delay, setinterval

I am making a slider that, moves to left when it is swiped to left, and, moves to right when swiped to right. Her is what I've achieved till now https://jsfiddle.net/6ze720f7/ . Although I can now just set position left: 0 when left is displayed and position left: 446 px when Right is displayed.

The code that takes care of the direction is:

```
center.onmousemove = function(Dmove) {
if (Dmove.pageX < oldx) {
    direction = "left"
} else if (Dmove.pageX > oldx) {
    direction = "right"
}

oldx = Dmove.pageX;
}
```

What I am worried about is that the difference between `oldx` and `Dmove.pageX` is very very small, more precisely the amount of time taken in the execution of a few lines of javascript code. So if the `div` is swiped to left for 1 second but at the end it is moved to right, by mistake, for a few milliseconds then the `div` will be swiped to right. The solution I thought is to use 10ms older value of `oldx`.

- Is it possible to find 10 millisecond older value than present of `Dmove.pageX`?
- Is it possible to give a **synchronous** delay of 10 millisecond after the statement `oldx = Dmove.pageX;`?
- Is it possible to use `setInterval()` function in such a way that it would set the value `oldx` after every 10 second? This could be a little problematic because the difference between `oldx` and present value of `Dmove.pageX` could be taken anything between 0 to 10ms when the `mouseup` event happens.

Comment: `10ms` is a really short time. But you could for example set a `10ms` timeout after each mousemove that will update the "oldx". Using this methond you will create `100` timeouts each second, which is not really great in terms of performance. Again, `10ms` is a really short time I think you should increase it to something like `50ms` at least.

Comment: Another option can be to save all mouse positions along with their timestamps in a queue. Every time first item in queue is older than 10ms pop it from the queue. Add new items at the end of the queue. To find the position that happened 10ms ago just read the first value in queue.

Comment: @Cristy Wouldn't setting a 10ms timeout after each mousmove event cause blurring effect on the movement of `div`?

Comment: This is a common software/hardware feedback loop problem and is usually solved by implementing a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).  There is no need to store all the mouse position values.

Comment: I can realize this effect on my optical mouse. On very slow motion to the left my mouse pointer sometimes jumps right. Just store the mouse position in an array with a write pointer `px++ ; mousex[px &= 3]` would circulate 4 items. `mousex[px^1]` swiches between 2 items, if it is initially 0 or 1. The modulo operation lets you chose any amount, but it is less performant. Storing +/-differences avoids expensive divisions on avarage calculation.

Comment: @Roberto How would you implement that in this case? I think you still have to save the positions, otherwise you would have no way to "exclude the first item and include the next one". And the moving average method gives only approximate values (because values are average), but in his case he needs the exact values.

Comment: @Cristy Only a few latest move events are taken as mentioned in my comment. It happens that the mouse moves right, but the signal says left. Economic devices are not made to provide high precision measurements. Also users can do a little movement when releasing the mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest (if applicable for your case) to adopt another approach: compare the x position at the start of the swipe(i.e: start of the drag or the mosedown event), and the x position at the end or during the swipe (i.e: the mouseup or the mousemove events). Which gives:

```
document.body.onmousedown = function(Dmove) { 
    oldx = Dmove.pageX;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Don't modify `oldx` elsewhere and compare to that "initial" value in your `onmousedown` or `onmouseup` event listeners.

Comment: This is completely wring approach. Suppose the initial x position is 50. Now I swipe the div to `x=10` and then back to `x=25`. Overall the x position decreases but actually at the end the user wants to swipe to right. With your method the div will swipe to left.

Comment: @user31782 Since you update `oldx` on every mouse move, an initial setting just makes mousemove more accurate from the first pixel movement.

Comment: @user31782 This is why I said "if applicable for your case". My appraoch does the following:1. if the user starts swiping (or dragging) at "x:50", passes by "x:10" but does not release the mouse (or move up finger) and then goes to "x:25", the swipe is considered left. 2.In the other hand, if the user starts swiping (or dragging) at "x:50", releases at "x:10" and then swipe again to "x:25", this second swipe is considered right.